# Divided powers in the context of elements of the Schur algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am currently reading through the paper [Presenting Schur algebras as quotients of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_2$](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010005v1.pdf).

Here it defines the following matrices $e := \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, f:= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

The paper repeatedly refers to the *divided powers* $e^{(a)} := \frac{e^a}{a!}$ and $f^{(a)}$ similarly. However, for $a \ge 2$ would we not get that these divided powers are zero, unless $e^{a}$ does not mean the normal power but then what else could it mean?

Also another notational item, it states the schur algebra $S(2,r)$ is a quotient of the universal enveloping algebra $\mathfrak{U(gl)}$ subject to the relations:

(R1): $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix} = r$

(R2): $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} - 1)(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} - 2)...(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix} - r + 1) = 0$

I have no idea how two matrices can add to a number to get the relations.

Could someone please explain this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $e$ is an element of a universal enveloping algebra, and $e^a$ is taken in the UEA - it is not a power obtained by doing matrix multiplication.

Comment: R1 and R2 are a mild abuse of notation.  Imposing the relation R1 means taking the quotient of the uea by the two sided ideal generated by $H_1+e+f-r$. Then the images $\bar{H_1}, \bar{e}, \bar{f}$ of the elements $H_1, e, f$ in this quotient satisfy the relation $\bar{H_1} + \bar{e} + \bar{f} = \bar{r}$.

Comment: Do you understand the definition of a universal enveloping algebra in general? (Well enough that, for example, you can explain why $U(\mathfrak{gl}_2)$ is infinite-dimensional?)

Comment: I was under the assumption that the Universal Enveloping Algebra was a quotient of the tensor algebra, where we factor out the ideal generated by $[x,y] - x \otimes y - y \otimes x$, and hence it is infinite dimensional. Also @mt_ am I wrong in thinking $r$ is the scalar in $S(2,r)$?

Comment: Can someone also explain what the powers $e^a, f^a$ are in the UEA if they are not the usual matrix powers?

Comment: if you construct the uea as a quotient of the tensor algebra, $e^a$ here means the image in the quotient of $e\otimes \cdots \otimes e$ where there are $a$ copies of $e$. You're not wrong about $r$ being the $r$ from $S(2,r)$.

Comment: So then how do we make sense of $H_1 -r$, as this looks like adding a matrix to a scalar or is $r =r \cdot I_2$?